# how do I pass table row data to a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple rows table with rows looks like below.   the last column has an edit button that when I click, it will make a  visible with 5 input text area to update the values in the table on a refresh.

I need to pass val1,val2,val3,val4,val5 in the particular row to  using jquery.   But I get nothing when I try $('#val1').val()

Any suggestion on how to connect the click to the form values would be appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

```html
'<tr>'
+ '<td id="val1">' + val1+ '</td>'
+ '<td id="val1">' + val2+ '</td>'
+ '<td id="val1">' + val3+ '</td>'
+ '<td id="val1">' + val4+ '</td>'
+ '<td id="val1">' + val5+ '</td>'
+ '<td> <button class="edit-row display-mode" id="edited">Edit</button>'
+ '<button class="cancel-row display-mode" id="canceled">Cancel</button></td>'
+ '</tr>');
```

Comment: This is very unclear as to what you are asking.

Comment: sorry, the code was chopped off.  I re-edited

Comment: That code snippet doesn't do much when you run it... Maybe you meant to use code formatting, not a snippet? Also, you'll want to include more code, since that's not a complete set of jQuery code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#val1').val()` looks for a value attribute of a tag.
Change it to `$('#val1').text()` to get what is inside the table cell.